# cloud9, cannot link js file to ejs

Tags: javascript, directory, cloud9

I am new to server programming.

I cannot get the bootstrap js files to link to my ejs file. I am trying to link the js files to index.ejs.

I have this code:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

They are in the same original folder, so why doesn't this work?
Thanks for your help

[Screenshot of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBARB.png)